# How to nest formatted strings in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to nest formatted strings in XAML without creating a custom class?

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

- Format a string, e.g. `"inner start {0} inner end"`.
- Format the previous resultant string, e.g. `"outer start {0} outer end"`.
- Use the final string as the `Text` of a `TextBlock`.

As a concrete example, if `"foo"` was the string to be formatted, I would require the final string to be:

`"outer start inner start foo inner end outer end"`

I am able to format a single string with the following:

```
<TextBlock
Text="{Binding Source={x:Static res:Resources.Foo}, StringFormat={x:Static res:Resources.Bar}}" />
```

However, attempting to bind one `Binding` to another results in an error:

```
<TextBlock
Text="{Binding Source={Binding Source={x:Static res:Resources.Foo}, StringFormat={x:Static res:Resources.Bar}}, StringFormat={x:Static res:Resources.Baz}}" />
```

I think this could be achieved with an `IMultiValueConverter`, but I don't know if there is a simpler way.

Comment: The `Binding.StringFormat` property is meant to format the binding source value. Since a `Binding` can only have a single source, you can only format a single input. If you need to format multiple inputs i.e. binding sources, then use `MultiBinding`. You should consider to format the string in the binding source. This should be more convenient to maintain.

Comment: @BionicCode from the examples I have seen, I think that using `MultiBinding` with nested format strings would require `IMultiValueConverter`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. MultiBinding always needs a converter to know how to merge the multiple values.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to achieve what I wanted with the following:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="FooBar"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type system:String}"
                            MethodName="Format">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Static Member="res:Resources.Foo" />
                <x:Static Member="res:Resources.Bar" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TextBlock
        Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource FooBar}, StringFormat={x:Static res:Resources.Baz}}" />
</Grid>
```

In the above:

- `x` is `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`
- `res` is the .NET namespace (and assembly)

  - e.g. `xmlns:res="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp"`